# TabView is loading all app tabs when the app loads

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am just starting with Nativescript and I really am impressed with all that work!

As part of a project to move a VueJS web app to mobile, I am trying to work with tabview and understand this. One element that I cannot seem to figure out is a behaviour that I have that seems to defer with the doc:

> The iOS implementation uses UITabBarController. This means that only one TabViewItem can be shown at a given time and only one needs to be loaded. When the user selects a new TabViewItem, we load the new item and unload the previous one._

My tabview looks like this:

```
<TabView selectedTabTextColor="#d94b3f"
     class="fas"
     fontSize="60"
     androidTabsPosition="bottom"
     androidOffscreenTabLimit="1">
    <TabViewItem title="T1" fontSize="60">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Comp1 />
        </GridLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="T2" fontSize="60">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Comp2 />
        </GridLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="T4" fontSize="60">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Comp3 />
        </GridLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

In each of the component `mounted()` I have added a console.log(‘tab_name’). When I load the app, each console.log are loaded. From what I get in the doc, I should be only mounted when navigating to the tab.
Am I missing something? For now, the only solution I have is to use a combination of current index and v-if to render tab content.

Thanks a lot!

Ed

Comment: I have the same issue on this, do you have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you forgot add the `selectedIndex` to the `TabView`.

The result should be

```
<TabView selectedTabTextColor="#d94b3f" class="fas"
     fontSize="60" androidTabsPosition="bottom" androidOffscreenTabLimit="1"
     selectedIndex="selectedIndex" @selectedIndexChange="indexChange"
>
    <TabViewItem title="T1" fontSize="60">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Comp1 />
        </GridLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="T2" fontSize="60">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Comp2 />
        </GridLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="T4" fontSize="60">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Comp3 />
        </GridLayout>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>

methods: {
  indexChange: function(args) {
      let newIndex = args.value
      console.log('Current tab index: ' + newIndex)
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I will have a look at this right away an see how things goes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I hadn't been able to test it yet. So my code looks exactly like the one you sent, and I still have the 3 mounted triggered at once. The console.log "Current tab index" returns NaN on load, then it returns the correct index when navigating. I am. still making some test to understand this better.

Comment: Did you add `selectedIndex` to your data? And set it to 1?

Comment: Same thing :( Sorry for the late reply, I am on vacation this week.

Comment: No problem take your time to relax and enjoy, if you have time would it be possible to make a playground example? https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue